# Unable to Get values from Web Form to a PHP Class to Display

Tags: php, class

I am having troubles getting the value from my variables submitted via a web form using a PHP class file.

Here is my structure of the web page:

- Order Form Page
- Process.php Page
- Book.php Page

I can easily get the user data entered (on Order Form Page), process, and display it on the Process.php page.  The issue is that I must create a Book class and print the details of the data using the Book class.

I have an empty constructor printing out "created" so I know my constructor is being called.  I also am able to print the word "title" so I know I can print to the screen by using the Book class.

My issue is that I can't get values in my variables in the Book class.

Here is my variable declaration:

```
    private $title;
```

Here is my printDetails function:

```
    public function printDetails () {
    echo "Title: " . $this->title . "<br />";
    }
```

Here is my new instance of the book class:

```
    $bookNow = new book;
```

Here are my get and set functions:

```
    function __getTitle($title)
{
    return $this->$title;
}

    function __setTitle($title,$value)
{
    $this->$title = $value;
}
```

I do have four other variables that I'm looking to display as well.  Each of those have their own variable declaration, a line in printDetails, and their own setter and getter.

Lastly, I also have a call to the Book class in my process PHP.  It looks like this:

```
    function __autoload($book) {
        include $book . '.php'; 
    }
    $bookNow = new book();
```

Any help, much appreciated.  It must be something so very small (I'm hoping).

Comment: how you are calling __setTitle ?

Comment: `$bookNow = new book();`  - add parentheses?  You say the class is in `Book.php`.  Then maybe `book()` should be `Book()` as well?

Comment: @GBD how you are calling __setTitle ?

I think this is my issue.  I have a form that collects the data, I can have it displayed in the process.php.  However, the values don't "move" to book class.

Any idea how I can call the setTitle in the book class?

Comment: Also, shouldn't your `__getTitle()` and `__setTitle()` methods start with single underscore?  I think PHP treats functions with double underscore as special (magic).

Comment: @Stefan Also, shouldn't your __get and __set methods start with single underscore? I think PHP treats functions with double underscore as special...................I tried one underscore, no difference.

Comment: You call it like this: `$bookNow->_setTitle($_POST["title"]);`

Comment: @kentrenholm $bookNow->_setTitle("title",$_POST["title"]);

Comment: `setTitle()` should have only one argument, namely the value

Comment: @Stefan that makes so much sense.  I tried it.  It is not working.  I know I am making a silly mistake.  You have pointed me in the right direction, and I give you props for that help.  Wish I could report it worked.  Silly mistakes.

Comment: @Stefan  I have
'code'function setTitle($value)
 {
  $this->$value;
 }

and getting my value with:
'code' $bookNow->setTitle=($_POST['title']);

Just does not seem to work

Comment: Please read my answer below.  You must also remove the 2nd `$` character in the assignment.

Comment: @Stefan sorry . . . if you mean this, it still is not working: function setTitle($value)
 {
  $this->value;
 }

Comment: @Stefan thanks regardless.  I'm closer.  I can feel it.

Comment: No problem. Check that your code looks like the class I added in an edit to my answer.

Comment: @Stefan last question.  Since the value is first coming to the process.php, and it is stored as variable $title, would I still be getting the variable from the POST method or from the process.php file somehow????

Comment: Check to make sure if you get the POSTED title, as shown in my answer. If you call the `Book()` constructor and methods in your process.php file (which is the action of your form) then the POST variables and the $title created variable will be available to you.  If however you redirect to a new page after processing, you will have to pass the POSTED values or created variables along as well when you redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_setTitle()` should have only one argument, and remove the second `$` character in the assignment statement (also for `getTitle()`), like so:

```
function _setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;
}
```

Now call it like this:

```
$title = !empty($_POST["title"]) ? $_POST["title"] : NULL;
$bookNow->_setTitle($title);
```

And don't use double underscore unless you are dealing with magic functions. I think that is bad practice.  Also check the case of your class - even though php is very relaxed about case.  If your class file is called "Book.php" then your constructor should be called with uppercase just to make sure (and parentheses too probably).

EDIT:  OK this is the class I made and it works just fine, I tested it:

```
class Book {

    private $title;

    function __construct() {}

    function _getTitle($title)  {
        return $this->title;
    }

    function _setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function printDetails() {
        echo "Title: " . $this->title . "<br />";
    }

}
```

Make sure you get a value in the POST, like this:

```
$title = !empty($_POST["title"]) ? $_POST["title"] : 'No Title Found!';
$bookNow = new Book();
$bookNow->_setTitle($title);
$bookNow->printDetails();
```

NB:  DO NOT put the above statements inside the 'book.php' class file.

If your form submission went wrong, you will see 'No Title Found!', otherwise you will see the correct title.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know if it is not working because it is going through the process.php page before getting to the book.php  Thanks so much for your time and talent.  Hopefully I'll get it going.

Comment: @kentrenholm If `book.php` is your class file, rather don'tt put your `$bookNow = new book()` and `$bookNow->setTitle()` etc. statements INSIDE that file.  But either way, the autoload will include everything in process.php ad thus you will have acess to the POST values.

Comment: Appreciate your follow-up.  Made another attempt.  Perhaps it is because I'm taking in the values in the process.php file, and doing validation . . . I really don't know.  All of your sound logic and recommendations make a lot of sense.  Sorry to take up your time.